# Displaying html text in loop only once php

Tags: php, html, loops, if-statement, html-table

I am having difficulty in this matter, i have like 2 columns with name of URL and Status and i have to post data into this html table in a loop, the problem that i am facing is the column title keeps looping itself again and again but i want it only once...this is my code

```
    <?php
    if (preg_match("/found/", $html))
        {

    echo '<table id="table-2">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>URL</th>
<th>Status</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>'.$get_sites_link.'</td>
<td>Keyword Found</td>

</tr></tbody>
</table>';
    $vul_url[] = $get_sites_link1; 
    $links_duplicate_removed = array_unique($vul_url);
    file_put_contents($save_file, implode(PHP_EOL, $links_duplicate_removed));
    }
    else 
    {
    echo '<table id="table-2">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>URL</th>
<th>Status</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>'.$get_sites_link1.'</td>
<td>Keyword Not Found</td>

</tr></tbody>
</table>'."</b>"."</br>";

    }
    }

    ?>
```

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: This code by itself does not cause looping; or in fact, run. You're missing an end `}`

Comment: i have not posted all of the code...i have just posted the part where html is present...do i need to post all the code including end loop?

Comment: @NidaZubair Pasting the code that actually initiates (or contains in its entirety) the loop, would be *most* helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you should probably take the table opening and the header out of the loop. Something along the lines of:

```
echo "This is the only time this line will be shown.\n";
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    echo "This line was shown $i times!\n";
}
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/Tis4wU

Comment: Got it working! I put the html table tags out of the loop and all worked fine....thanks

Comment: @NidaZubair: No problem. If this answer helped you, consider accepting it by clicking the large green tick mark (V) under this answer's vote count.

Answer (score 0):

To show a thing many times, you need to iterate it, create a loop with:

- for
- foreach
- while
- do ... while

  `for($i=0; $i <=100; $i++){
      echo "It's the $i time that I show it";
  end`